# Why was Vanessa apparently allowed to go free?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, daredevil-tv

In the final episode of Daredevil season 1, "Daredevil", Matt convinces a cop who was on the take with, but hiding from, Fisk to divulge information about Fisk's crime ring and the people involved, leading to several arrests.

While it's likely he might not have named Vanessa as part of that process, the cops still found Fisk with her in his high rise when they arrested him, giving her a very expensive engagement ring and kissing her in the process.

**So why was she able to basically walk around free**? Wouldn't the cops want to bring her in for questioning or possibly put her under watch? Yet she makes it to a private helicopter with seemingly no fuss from anyone with authority and gets away.

Answer (score 3):

Given that Wilson Fisk is so private and so protective of Vanessa, it's highly unlikely that the low-level cop could have known about her. Without any evidence, she wouldn't have been arrested or even taken in for questioning at the end of the first season. Fisk also used his last remaining power and capital to make sure she got out of the country quickly and remained safe.

There isn't even enough proof that she knew about the criminal activity in the second season to revoke her visa, which is why Murdock is able to threaten Fisk.